# Apache : Display perl script as a text

Tags: perl, apache

I have Perl files with no extension (not in the format of .pl)
I need to execute them when I click them not open them as a plain text.

when I add pl extension to them. they work successfully. (when I added in apache.conf

```
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi  pl
```

)

but I need to know if there's a way to execute them without adding the extension

Comment: Is this what you are after? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptalias

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`SetHandler`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#sethandler) to decide what Apache treats as a cgi-script.

In apache configuration, add this and reload/restart Apache:

```
<Directory /path/to/directory/with/perl-files>
    SetHandler cgi-script
</Directory>

# Or <DirectoryMatch>, <Location>, <FilesMatch> or similar directives
```

**or**

In the directory itself, add file `.htaccess` with content:

```
SetHandler cgi-script
```

This will make Apache treat everything in the directory as a cgi-script and try to execute it regardless of file extension.

The `.htaccess` solution might need additional permissions in apache configuration, (like `AllowOverride SetHandler`) see [Apache Doc for AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride)